# Kenlm lmplz on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, kenlm

I used Kenlm to train a language model on Google Colab.
This is what i have in bin folder:

```
%cd /content/drive/My Drive/kenlm/build/bin
!ls

/content/drive/My Drive/kenlm/build/bin
 build_binary     'lm (1).en.arpa'   phrase_table_vocab         tst2012.en
 count_ngrams      lm_data       probing_hash_table_benchmark   tst2012.vi
 filter        lm_data.zip       query              tst2013.en
 fragment      lm.en.arpa        train.en               tst2013.vi
 kenlm_benchmark   lmplz         train.vi
```

I've in bin folder and I also put my "train.*" file there but when

```
!lmplz -o 3 <train.en> lm.en.arpa
```

Colab replied:

```
/bin/bash: lmplz: command not found"
```

How can I run it?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late to answer but it may help anyone goes in here after this.

As [kenlm's documentation](https://kheafield.com/code/kenlm/estimation/), the author only state that we should execute command outside `bin` directory. You can follow my script [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1U7yFQYNeQHAiYTnA9AhUEQqcZAYxl88I?authuser=2&hl=en#scrollTo=WRxP6dVkJALg).

**Note**: If anyone struggle compiling kenlm locally, remember to install all dependencies (as listed [here](https://kheafield.com/code/kenlm/dependencies/)) before `cmake`.